# Saving structs as cell elements (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, data-structures, struct, save, cell

I have been working with some MAT files (using MATLAB) which appear to be structured as groups of cells, where each cell has an *1xn* dimension and for *1* to *n*, there is a *1x1* struct.

While this may not be the most ideal way to handle the data I'm working with, I wishing to keep very similar code the one I have already invested some time in. I have been trying to recreate a similar structure from scratch, however upon defining a cell and struct, I am unaware how to include each struct in the cell.

I have tried simply using

```
cellexample(1,n) = structexample
```

However the following error message is quoted: "Conversion to cell from struct is not possible."

Any quick pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `{}` like so to set the value in cell:

```
cellexample{1,n} = structexample;
```